# The sound freezes while listening to music

Tags: windows-7, freeze, sound-card

I have bought an sound card - `Sound Blaster X-FI Surround 5.1 PRO` and while I'm listening to the music, after few minutes or even hours (it does happends randomly) the sound dissapears and I have to go settings: `Playing Devices` -> `Advanced` and switch the `Default Format` (sampling frequency) and switch from the `16-bits, 48000 Hz (DVD Quality) to any other from the list (16-bits, 96000 Hz **or** 24-bits, 48000 Hz **or** 24-bits 96000 Hz). I have been trying to set all of the above options, but for all of them the sound freezes after listening to music. It is getting annoying and I hope its the settings fault and not my sound card.

I got my drivers installed from the attached CD and I'm running Windows 7 HP 64 bits.
If anyone would try to help me, I would really appreciate this.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would try is downloading the drivers from the web. The drivers on CD's that come with hardware are usually always out of date, so it's best to download the latest drivers from the manufacturers website.

If the latest drivers don't make a difference I would have to put it down to faulty hardware.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeh I've downloaded the latest drivers with the auto update app and I think that update did cause that problem...